# Can't resize (FileVault) partition after Bootcamp removal

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, filevault, disk-space

I have a recent Mac with two partitions. The first one contains MacOS, and is encrypted with FileVault. The second one contained a Bootcamp Windows installation. Here is a screen shot:

[image: DiskUtility screen shot]

I deleted the Bootcamp partition to reclaim space. Turns out: as a FileVault partition can't be resized, it can not grow to use the extra space.

What must I do to have **one big partition** again?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/315803/how-do-i-resize-a-filevault-2-encrypted-partition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @alan-shutko pointed out with a hyperlink, the only way to resize a encrypted partition is to **disable encryption**, (rebooting again,) *then* changing the size. It worked for me!

It's a lengthy process if you wait for it, but bearable if you let the decryption happen overnight.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the **disabling encryption** is to use command `diskutil cs resizeStack`

The details on how it works has been documented by Klanomath [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume)

One thing I wanted to add is that it also works with FileVault. I have tried and the performance was pretty good. It took me 5-8 minutes to resize the 230GB partition to 250GB.

To sum it up:

Firstly: Boot from a separate system such as USB or the internet

Secondly: use this command `diskutil cs list` to get the volume Id of the **Logical Volume** partition

I.e:

```
        $ diskutil cs list
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
    |
    +-- Logical Volume Group A061B44A-9E3D-41B1-8943-C11BD76DDE37
        =========================================================
        Name:         Macintosh HD
        Status:       Online
        Size:         250337738752 B (250.3 GB)
        Free Space:   180224 B (180.2 KB)
        |
        +-< Physical Volume 01F57DD6-2209-4FA6-A085-93C36C36B3D4
        |   ----------------------------------------------------
        |   Index:    0
        |   Disk:     disk0s2
        |   Status:   Online
        |   Size:     250337738752 B (250.3 GB)
        |
        +-> Logical Volume Family 777A289D-71C0-43A2-9C10-39EFEE313964
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            Encryption Status:       Unlocked
            Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
            Conversion Status:       Complete
            Conversion Direction:    -none-
            Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
            Fully Secure:            Yes
            Passphrase Required:     Yes
            |
            +-> Logical Volume 11F03152-0861-4BA0-AA78-1F1D8CE520AF
                ---------------------------------------------------
                Disk:                  disk1
                Status:                Online
                Size (Total):          249999917056 B (250.0 GB)
                Conversion Progress:   -none-
                Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
                LV Name:               Macintosh HD
                Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
                Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

It is **11F03152-0861-4BA0-AA78-1F1D8CE520AF**

And you can use this command to resize:

```
diskutil cs resizeStack 11F03152-0861-4BA0-AA78-1F1D8CE520AF 250g
```