# Can't make more than two partitions

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility, partition

I want to multiboot my MacBook Pro, I'm trying to make partitions but in Disk Utility I can't make my partitions, only can divide by 2? Why?
**It's a normal SSD** not a fusion drive (SSD+HD).

Now I'm fresh installing my Mac with internet recovery... (Second time) but this time in Disk Utility by internet recovery instead click on **erase** I clicked in partitions and make a partition named **Macintosh HD**.

What I'm doing wrong?

Outputs:

diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 36635140-167F-4638-BF3C-4477ADAA6B21
                                 Unencrypted
```

diskutil cs list:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group C9D6D11C-1A54-4134-9F20-0DDEF2F0FCB2
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
    Free Space:   18882560 B (18.9 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume F1B297D0-081B-4E58-B1CB-7441FEF5F64D
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     250140434432 B (250.1 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 57E0CBD7-461B-4E2A-87E5-B1B3B8B1FFE5
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 36635140-167F-4638-BF3C-4477ADAA6B21
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          249769230336 B (249.8 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0:

```
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=251000193024; sectorsize=512; blocks=490234752
gpt show: disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 490234751
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488555536      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488965176    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Is it a Core Storage Volume [Logical Volume Group]? That info would show at bottom left in Disk Utility. If so, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume?lq=1

Comment: I can't know now but in 2014 I already made more than 2 partitions. I don't know why disk utility don't let me partition the disk now, something I do wrong?

Comment: depends entirely on whether it's core storage or not

Comment: I Installed new OS X Mavericks from Internet Recovery, but when I upgraded to Yosemite modified from Solid State Disk to Logical Volume Group... How do I reverse???

Comment: See the link I posted, klanomath's answer is as good as answers get on the subject

Comment: Didn't worked that link

Comment: that was quick;) what error did you get

Comment: Resizing to same size it can't

Comment: when I issue: **diskutil cs resizeStack [UUID] 0g** give me that error

Comment: done... edited and posted the results of diskutil list, diskutil cs list and sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva What kind of multi-boot environment do you need?

Comment: @klanomath See here please: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179626/same-swap-partition-in-multi-boot

Comment: @klanomath - glad to see you in on this one; it's above my pay grade;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to create a multi-boot environment you have to revert from a CoreStorage partition layout to a standard partition layout.

1. Start to internet recovery mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting.
2. Open Terminal.app in the menubar Utilities → Terminal
3. enter `diskutil cs revert LVUUID` and hit the <kbd>⏎</kbd> key.
   (LVUUID is the Logical Volume UUID. You get it by entering `diskutil cs list` in Terminal.app)
   In your case it's `diskutil cs revert 36635140-167F-4638-BF3C-4477ADAA6B21`.
   If your CoreStorage Volume is tagged as 'revertible' this command should convert your CoreStorage volume to a standard volume non-destructively.
4. Enter 'exit' when the conversion is finished and quit Terminal.app.
5. Open Disk Utility and partition your SSD as you need.

Comment: Thanks it worked.... Thank you very much.... By the way is there a editor to publish in stack exchange? How do you type/write the keys and how you make new lines without using br tag. Thanks again

Comment: And sorry for I don't left you a vote up, I can't yet I have not 15 reputation

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva Please check [editing-help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help). - keys: <kbd>key</kbd> - new line: two trailing spaces

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva BTW It's gonna be hard to create a 5-systems-boot environment. I don't know if it's even possible. Maybe you should consider VMware or Parallels...

Comment: FWIW, I've got a MB with 10.6 thru 10.10 all installed, as well as another partition with the 10.6 installer disk. Option-booting, with all the recovery partitions etc, is a screen full of hdd icons.

Comment: @Kent The 5 systems are Mac OS X, Windows 8.1, Debian, Ubuntu and Arch Linux!

Comment: Yikes!  Completely different scenario. I'd also be interested to see if that could even be done.

Comment: My final choices were: MAC OS X, Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 14.04.1, SlackWare and ArchLinux... But Slackware don't boot well: stops in "mousedev ps/2 mouse device common for all mice" and ArchLinux is a little difficult for me to install...

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva Can you please ask a question regarding this 5x-boot and answer it as well (that's explicitly allowed!) with a proper walk-through?

Comment: @klanomath Should I post here or in "Unix & Linux", that question of slackware

Comment: @DiogoSaraiva To get Slackware or ArchLinux running should probably be one question - i don't know if here or at U&L (i assume here because it's running on Apple hardware). The multi-boot environment install should be a second question here. I'm really curious how you got that working...

Comment: @klanomath With rEFInd....  I Initially make partition for OS X and used your help (answer) and make partitions for Windows 8.1, Ubuntu and Ubuntu Swap in Fat32... Next installed windows (i had to format fat32 partition to ntfs in windows installer) and when installed Ubuntu choose Ubuntu choosed "one more thing" to choose partitions... I had to make a few changes in refind configuration file too...