# Problem seeing Macintosh HD under Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I can't see the Macintosh HD partition under Windows 10 in Boot Camp. I've already followed some guides on how to solve this problem that talk about CoreStorage etc...

Now when I get this:

```
sudo diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

I still can't see the drive from Windows, what should I do?

- My Mac is a 13" Mid-2012
- macOS Sierra 10.12.3
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This a known issue that was introduced with the Windows 10 "Anniversary Update" as discussed,
for instance, [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30530792#30530792) or [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/251656/45492).