# Windows 10 not recognized mac high sierra (APFS system) partition

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, partition, apfs

Today i installed windows 10 ver 1607 on my macbook air with high sierra 10.13 on it. but i cant find my mac partition via windows 10. I tried repair it with step that suggested in this  forum:

[How can I make Mac Partition visible in Bootcamp (Windows 10 Anniversary Update)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251656/how-can-i-make-mac-partition-visible-in-bootcamp-windows-10-anniversary-update)

so after few tried, i found new partition, there was "Local Disk (D:)" with zero size. Of course I couldnt read my macintosh partition and windows suggested me for format it. so check disk management and found that mac partition still not have file system (RAW). then i realized that High Sierra had new system format that different with HFS format.

So can i make my windows read macintosh hd with APFS format? can someone give tutorial? i new in this type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to read APFS partitions with the tools provided by Apple's Boot Camp drivers or any other tool for Windows.

See also [Paragon's answer](https://kb.paragon-software.com/article/4250) regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more that can open APFS on Windows are [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/sol_und_m.php) and [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm). Both are read only. Have not found any that can write.

Answer (score 0):

[Biskus APFS Capture](http://biskus.com) is able to view and copy files from an APFS disk unter Windows. It's a bit pricey, though.

Answer (score 0):

[MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/) offers read-only access to APFS partitions. 
 
(At time of writing the APFS support is in **beta** state. It is currently only available on **Windows 10** and only supports **non-encrypted** APFS partitions.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution from Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows) (Preview, free at the moment). It works perfectly fine for me in read-only mode. I downloaded in, installed. Logged in with facebook account and mounted my Apple APFS partition.