# MacOS partition not working on bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, partition

I used bootcamp to create a new windows partition. It works fine, but I can't see the mac hard drive in my Devices and Drivers in windows. I know that you used to be able to read files from mac os.

I read this stackexchange question ([How can I make Mac Partition visible in Bootcamp (Windows 10 Anniversary Update)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251656/how-can-i-make-mac-partition-visible-in-bootcamp-windows-10-anniversary-update/252005)) but it didn't work. I had Bootcamp 6.0, but I installed the drivers from a site I found anyways. (It didn't work/change anything, I already had the registry keys) When I set "H:" to "\Device\HarddiskVolume2", it shows up as "Local Disk (H:)" instead of "Macintosh HD" or something. No other hard disk volume works; volume 1 is the 200MB partition, volume 3 is the windows partition, and no other volumes show up. When I open the Local Disk (H:), it asks me to reformat the hard drive.

[image: local disk]

In my disk management, my macos partition still doesn't show up as HFS, even though I have all the right drivers.

[image: disk management]

What's the problem? I'm on windows 10, version 1909.

Edit: Forgot to add, whenever I click "Restart in OS X" in windows, it tells me that it failed to locate the OS X boot volume.

Comment: I assume here when you stated bootcamp, you referring to Windows 10. There is a Golden Rule which roughly states: *Never change the partitioning on a Mac from Windows*. There are exceptions to this rule, but I do no think any apply in this case.

Comment: @DavidAnderson If that's the case, then how could I set up windows so I can read the files on my mac?

Comment: Windows looks at the contents of a partition to determine the volume format. Since Apple's software modifies Windows so Windows can read read HFS+ partitions, Windows will think HFS+ partitions are Windows partitions. This can cause Windows partitioning software to work incorrectly.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I'm not setting up partitions from windows. I'm just trying to set up the drivers so that I can read the files in the existing mac partition from windows.

Comment: What macOS are you on? Windows can't read APFS disks & neither can the boot camp software inside Windows. You have to swap back to macOS by holding Opt at boot.

Comment: @Tetsujin Catalina. I can boot back and forth between windows and macos just fine, just pressing “boot into OS X” gives an error. I want to be able to read the macros files from windows. The SO question I posted tells me it’s possible with the right drivers, but it’s not working.

Comment: The linked question is about HFS+ not APFS. The BC control panel can read HFS+ but not APFS. You need 3rd party software in Windows to read it. Something like https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/ though I don't know if it will enable the control panel to work.

Comment: Ok thanks, did not realize there was a new file system.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot read APFS volumes. Boot Camp support software provides HFS+ drivers, not APFS. You will need third-party software to read files from APFS disks, such as https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/ (no affiliation and not tested).