# Cannot Repair Macintosh HD, after loading into OS X, it becomes an X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, error

When I restart the computer and it's loading with the Apple logo, waiting for few seconds, then the apple icon becomes an X.
My Mac is OS X El Capitan (v10.11.3).

I used Disk Utility "First Aid" and found that ‘incomplete or inconsistent CoreStorage Physical Volume’.

[image: incomplete or inconsistent CoreStorage Physical Volume]

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            1.6 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 932901B0-86C0-489B-B492-D3CB3F6BE923
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         1717036040192 B (1.7 TB)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 4DD9C769-C5EC-4CBE-9A00-B126B6E746A5
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Checking
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 391CC257-4157-411B-8001-837851BFB255
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Checking
    |   Size:     1596047187968 B (1.6 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 6996BC17-40A4-40A6-8590-758665B98BC4
        ----------------------------------------------------
        (No properties)
```

I am trying to repair my disk with 0 Free Space.

I checked [How to add free space to a Logical Volume Group? (Resizing Partitions)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172043/how-to-add-free-space-to-a-logical-volume-group-resizing-partitions) but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Seems to be it couldn't find the system folder](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156), which doesn't mean that the disk/partition is bad (thus the "good" on Disk Utility). You're right on the "no free space" thing, and unfortunately, I don't think we can help further unless you provide more info. What exactly isn't working when you try to add free space?

Comment: um.....i tried for one day by using recovery mode (cmd+r), but it not working. Then i go to mac internet recovery mode (alt + cmd + r), and open the "old style" Disk Utility, Disk Utility said my disk is damaged, need to repair, and pressed one button to fix it... but all of my data are erased...

i had no idea why the new one (osx el Capitan) Disk Utility cannot repair the fusion disk...

Comment: Seems like you used a version of Disk Utility that was old enough that it didn't properly support your Logical Volume setup. Do you plan on attempting to recovery your data?

Comment: no... my backup is out of date....Is the new one Disk Utility that cannot support Logical Volume setup