# Recovery HD left in the middle

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I did some partitioning to install Linux. Then I decided to erase that partition altogether. Now I am left with a configuration like this:

[image: current partition setup]

How can I add the free space to main partition?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `diskutil cs list` entered in Terminal.app to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a solution and posted it below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing or expanding a CoreStorage volume](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume)

Comment: I dont think this was duplicate, since my main problem is that I have a RecoveryHD in the middle, which prevents extending my main HD.

Comment: In similar cases (after installing Windows/Linux and deleting the new partition manually afterwards) the Recovery HD is always "in the middle". Check the `gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk0` example listing in the accepted answer. The Recovery HD is the 3rd partition (i=3), followed by an invisible UEFI-partition (i=4) and a lot of unallocated free space.

Answer (score 1):

I created a bootable usb with unetbootin and Gparted. I booted the mac with the stick. i moved my Recovery HD to the end. Then I rebooted normally, opened up Disk Utility, dragged the end of the main partition to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is also posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume). It works with standard (build-in) OS X system tools. Depending on your partition table and the CoreStorage listing some slight adjustments may be necessary.