# Bootcamp 40GB error

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I have a problem on boot camp where when I try to click continue but I get this message. Can anyone help?

> The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned.
>   You must have at least 40GB of free space available.

[image: The Error Message]

[image: About this mac says this]

Possible Fixes

1. It could maybe be time machine since I have it enabled. But as you know High Sierra does not give you the time machine off switch in system preferences
2. It could also be a disk utility partition error but you can clearly see on the image below I only have 1 partition which is my main OS hard drive[image: I only have 1 partition]

Comment: It says you need 40gb to proceed. Disk utility indicates that you have 35gb free. Are you able to make a total of 40gb free space and retry? Is there some other information that would be relevant?

Comment: I tried it on my mate's computer and he had 50GB but it still gave me the same error (message

Comment: It's saying that it's not going to try until there's 40gb free. If you start there and still have problems we can look at where to move forward from there.

Answer (score 2):

You need 40 GB of 'real' free space. The 'Available including Purgeable' figure doesn't count.

This is the one you need to be 40GB minimum...

[image]

Also, why not start with virtualization instead of boot camp. With that little free space, you will have run out of growth area for macOS. You might be much happier if you had 80 GB free before you decide to wall off 40 GB or more for Boot Camp since you can’t easily reclaim or change that allocation once you start down the boot camp path.

- [Resizing or expanding a CoreStorage volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154964/resizing-or-expanding-a-corestorage-volume)
- [Create a partition that both Windows and macOS Sierra can access via Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350964/create-a-partition-that-both-windows-and-macos-sierra-can-access-via-disk-utilit)
- [Boot Camp partition removal failed in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300608/boot-camp-partition-removal-failed-in-macos-sierra)
- [The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. Windows 10 and Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344478/the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-partition-window)