# Can't remap partitions to one main disk even in macOS Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I did bootcamp but it failed between so it end up making another volume which cannot be revert back to the mother disk and i tried but i couldn't (-minus) sign is not appearing on microsoft disk which is disk the partition even from recovery mode.

All I want to do is get back to the one main disk and wipe all other disk images but it is not happening, please help.

Comment: Duplicate of [The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. Windows 10 and Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344478/the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-partition-window). After retracting a (not really fitting) duplicate flag, I can't set another one!

Comment: found the solution, after erasing the whole device which is ssd both disk disappeared and recollected into one but sadly lost all data, didn't backup too