# I have a 2014 MacBook Pro which currently has 81.68 GB of available storage, why does it error out when installing Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I read on the Internet that it could possibly be erroring out due to lack of space. Hence, I deleted a bunch of stuff to free up almost 82 GB of storage.

Why am I still getting the error for Big Sur?

Comment: What's exactly the error you get? You can try Reset SMC, Reset NVRAM. From the terminal you can delete localsnapshots : `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 99999999999 4` then retry the update after doing a save Time Machine or a clone of the actual system of course.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336811/85275