# Went to High Sierra via clean install instead of upgrade by wiping "Macintosh HD". Old boot camp now is unable to "locate the macOS boot volume"

Tags: bootcamp, startup

It's actually just a minor inconvenience because I can reboot and hold down Option to get back into High Sierra.

I'm mainly hoping to find out if there is a way to "update" this existing boot camp installation so that it can find the new macOS volume again. That way I won't want to try to reinstall windows *again*.

I'm sure it's just some partition/volume handle setting stored somewhere in the bootcamp system in Windows.

Comment: Have a look at this question and consider editing in your `diskutil list` and `gpt` info - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176557/5472

Comment: I think this is macOS Sierra's problem, even with a clean install and new Bootcamp partition. My Bootcamp, can't locate macOS volume.

Comment: @gioalexiou can you confirm you're talking about High Sierra 10.13?

Comment: @StevenLu my mistake, I mean High Sierra in my comment above! Nevertheless if your problem is just the primary OS for booting you can change this through Startup Manager!

Comment: Yeah the workaround works fine it’s just not clean because you have to re-target macOS after you re-enter it via opt key boot