# Lost space after removing bootcamp partition via bootcamp assistant

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

please help 
i lost 150gb space after deleting the partition via boot camp assistant and the disk utility won't recover it or partition it as one disk 
i tried to recover by timemachine but the disk looked the same size and iam afraid the restore wont get the space back

[image: here's a disklist]

[image: disk utility won't partition]

Comment: Enter the command `sudo diskutil cs resizestack 9AE37A0F-B74E-4266-896D-1A84C5EF7D0B 0` in a Terminal application window. If this command does not work, then either post a comment or edit your questioin and say so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the size in the last shown screenshot by entering a new size in the field or dragging the white dot to the top in the chart on the left.

If this does not work, you need to manually resize the CoreStorage via the recovery system. [Look here how to do it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176557/282847).